# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении: ты прелесть(,) хотя я тебя даже не знаю

Comment: @dedMoroz, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Да, запятая в данном случае ставится в обязательном порядке как знак, разделяющий главную часть от придаточной. Во-первых, давайте рассмотрим предикативные основы данного предложения. Их две: [Ты прелесть] и [Я не знаю]. Оба простых предложения двусоставного вида (присутствуют оба главных члена предложения). Что касается самого предложения, то в данном случае мы имеем *придаточное уступительном* (возможно, ошибаюсь с классификацией придаточных).

Answer (score 0):

Да,запятая ставится.